# How to move all key-values of nested JSON object to parent in Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a JSON object with 3 nested objects at first level.

```
data{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2",
    "section1":"{"key1_1":"value1_1", "key1_2":"value1_2"}",
    "section2":"{"key2_1":"value2_1", "key2_2":"value2_2", "key2_3":"value2_3"}",
    "section3":"{"key3_1":"value3_1"}"
}
```

Now, using NODE.JS, I need to move all key-value from nested to parent object with all keys-values at root level, like this:

```
data{
"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2","key1_1":"value1_1", "key1_2":"value1_2", "key2_1":"value2_1", "key2_2":"value2_2", "key2_3":"value2_3", "key3_1":"value3_1"
}
```

Comment: What you have posted, is neither valid JSON, or even valid Javascript Object..

Comment: unfortunately data is exactly like that... with :"{". These are JSON strings inside sections.

Comment: how do you know, which one contains serialized data?

Comment: source owner assured me

Comment: @HassanNaqvi, i do not understand which property does contain a json string?

Comment: values of section keys are JSONObjects converted with toString()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a proper object, you could iterate the keys and if an object is found, call the function again with the content of the found object.

```js
function flat(source, target) {
    Object.keys(source).forEach(function (k) {
        if (source[k]!== null && typeof source[k] === 'object') {
            flat(source[k], target);
            return;
        }
        target[k] = source[k];
    });
}

var data = { "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "section1": { "key1_1": "value1_1", "key1_2": "value1_2" }, "section2": { "key2_1": "value2_1", "key2_2": "value2_2", "key2_3": "value2_3" }, "section3": { "key3_1": "value3_1" } },
    flatObject = {};

flat(data, flatObject);
console.log(flatObject);
```

Version with [JSON](http://json.org/) strings as value and a [`try ... catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) statement for testing if the value is a JSON.

```js
function flat(source, target) {
    Object.keys(source).forEach(function (k) {
        var o;
        try {
            o = JSON.parse(source[k]);
            if (o && typeof o === 'object') {
                flat(o, target);
            } else {
                target[k] = o;
            }
        } catch (e) {
            target[k] = source[k];
        }
    });
}

var data = { "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "section1": "{\"key1_1\":\"value1_1\", \"key1_2\":\"value1_2\"}", "section2": "{\"key2_1\":\"value2_1\", \"key2_2\":\"value2_2\", \"key2_3\":\"value2_3\"}", "section3": "{\"key3_1\":\"value3_1\"}" },
    flatObject = {};

flat(data, flatObject);
console.log(flatObject);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can recursively traverse your data and add it to an empty map:

```js
var data = {
    "key1":"value1", "key2":"value2",
    "section1":{"key1_1":"value1_1", "key1_2":"value1_2"},
    "section2":{"key2_1":"value2_1", "key2_2":"value2_2", "key2_3":"value2_3"},
    "section3":{"key3_1":"value3_1"}
}
var fill = function(carry, obj) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            continue;
        }
        if (obj[key] instanceof Object) {
            fill(carry, obj[key]);
        }
        else {
            carry[key] = obj[key];
        }
    }
    return carry;
}
var output = {}
fill(output, data);
console.log(output);
```